# ScopedExit implementation: pass arguments to the function object

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

I'm trying to implement simple ScopedExit class. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<class R, class... Args>
class ScopedExit
{
public:
    ScopedExit(std::function<R(Args...)> exitFunction)
    {
        exitFunc_ = exitFunction; 
    }

    ~ScopedExit()
    {
        exitFunc_();
    }
private:
    std::function<R(Args...)> exitFunc_;
};

template<>
class ScopedExit<void>
{
public:
    ScopedExit(std::function<void ()> exitFunction)
    {
        exitFunc_ = exitFunction; 
    }

    ~ScopedExit()
    {
        exitFunc_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void ()> exitFunc_;
};

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo() called\n";
}

class Bar
{
public:
    void BarExitFunc(int x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "BarExitFunc called with x =" << x << "y = " << y << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    std::cout << "Register scoped exit func\n";
    {
        ScopedExit<void, int, int> exitGuardInner(std::bind(&Bar::BarExitFunc, &b, 18, 11));
    }
    ScopedExit exitGuardOutter(foo);
    std::cout << "About to exit from the scope\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So, there are a couple of questions:

1. How to pass exit's function arguments to it? For example, I bind BarExitFunc with two integer arguments: 18 and 11. So how can I pass it to the exitFunc_ in the destructor? I think I need something like invoke function with std::forward<>.
2. gcc 4.7.2 (from ideone.com) complains about exitGuardOutter. It says:

> prog.cpp:60:16: error: missing template arguments before ‘exitGuardOutter’
>
> prog.cpp:60:16: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘exitGuardOutter’

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to pass exit's function arguments to it? For example, I bind BarExitFunc with two integer arguments: 18 and 11. So how can I pass it to the exitFunc_ in the destructor?

I can see no reason whatsoever to pass arguments to `exitFunc_` at call time in the destructor. Whatever you do, you'll have to provide those arguments upfront in the `ScopedExit` constructor anyway.

The most straightforward way is simply to use a `function<R()>` and `bind` any required arguments at the definition site like you're already doing:

```
ScopedExit<R> guard(std::bind(someFunction, someArg, otherArg));
```

This allows you to get rid of the variadic template arguments altogether and simplifies your template *a lot*.

---

Now, if what is bothering you is that you have to type `std::bind` and you would rather use such a syntax:

```
ScopedExit<R> guard(someFunction, someArg, otherArg);
```

Really, I don't see the point since it makes the template more complicated, but why not... Just bind/forward the arguments in the constructor itself and still store a `function<R()>`:

```
template<typename... Args>
ScopedExit(std::function<R(Args...)> exitFunction, Args&&... args)
{
    exitFunc_ = std::bind(exitFunction, std::forward<Args>(args)...); 
}
```

Now you systematically `bind` the function even if there are no arguments to bind, so you may want to specialize your class to avoid this useless `bind` when there are no arguments. This is left as an exercise.

---

> gcc 4.7.2 (from ideone.com) complains about exitGuardOutter

This is because `foo` isn't a `std::function` and the compiler can't deduce the correct template arguments. As already mentioned by @ForEveR you could just define your guard variable as `ScopedExit<void> guard(foo);`.

Or, **wrapping it all up** and keeping in mind what I first said (`bind` is best left out of your template and used at the definition site of your guard) you could just get rid of `std::function` in the constructor and generalize for any functor (which, BTW, is how the Standard library does whenever it needs a functor/callback). For storage you can just use `std::function<void()>` since it accepts non-void return types too:

```
class ScopedExit
{
public:
    template<typename Functor>
    ScopedExit(Functor exitFunction)
    {
        exitFunc_ = exitFunction; 
    }

    ~ScopedExit()
    {
        exitFunc_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void()> exitFunc_;
};

int foo() { return 0; }

struct Bar {
  void bye(int, int) {}
};

struct Baz {
  void operator ()() {}
};

int main() {
    const std::string what = "lambda!";
    ScopedExit guard1([&]() { std::cout << "yay a " << what << std::endl; });

    ScopedExit guard2(foo); // note how std::function<void()> accepts non-void return types

    Bar b;
    ScopedExit guard3(std::bind(&Bar::bye, &b, 1, 2));

    ScopedExit guard4(Baz());
}
```

Note how your original variadic template class has now become a flexible non-template class with just a templated constructor whose template argument is deduced automatically, and which accepts almost<sup>[see note below]</sup> any kind of functor you can think about.

---

**Note:** I said *almost* any functor because this doesn't work with default arguments:

```
void foobar(int = 0) {}
ScopedExit guard5(foobar); // error: too few arguments to function
```

Even if you stored a `Functor` directly instead of a `std::function<void()>` you wouldn't be able to make use of the default arguments anyway (the signature of `foobar` is still `void(int)` even with a default argument) so one always has to handle this corner-case at the definition site with something like:

```
void foobar(int = 0) {}
ScopedExit guard5([]() { foobar(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You can save arguments in `tuple` for example. However, in your case, you can simply call `exitFunc_()` and function definition should be `std::function<R()> exitFunction` since you already bind arguments to function. Something like this probably

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>

template<size_t...>
struct indices {};
template<size_t N, size_t... Is>
struct gen_indices : gen_indices<N - 1, N - 1, Is...>
{
};
template<size_t... Is>
struct gen_indices<0, Is...> : indices<Is...>
{
};

template<class R, class... Args>
class ScopedExit
{
public:
    ScopedExit(std::function<R(Args...)> exitFunction, Args&&... args)
    : arguments_(std::forward_as_tuple(args...))
    {
        exitFunc_ = exitFunction;
    }

    ~ScopedExit()
    {
       call(gen_indices<sizeof...(Args)>());
    }
private:
    template<size_t... Idx>
    void call(indices<Idx...>)
    {
       exitFunc_(std::forward<Args>(std::get<Idx>(arguments_))...);
    }
    std::tuple<Args...> arguments_;
    std::function<R(Args...)> exitFunc_;
};

template<>
class ScopedExit<void>
{
public:
    ScopedExit(std::function<void ()> exitFunction)
    {
        exitFunc_ = exitFunction; 
    }

    ~ScopedExit()
    {
        exitFunc_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void ()> exitFunc_;
};

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo() called\n";
}

class Bar
{
public:
    void BarExitFunc(int x, int y)
    {
        std::cout << "BarExitFunc called with x =" << x << "y = " << y << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bar b;
    std::cout << "Register scoped exit func\n";
    {
        ScopedExit<void, int, int> exitGuardInner
        (
           std::bind(&Bar::BarExitFunc, &b, std::placeholders::_1, 
           std::placeholders::_2), 10, 18
        );
    }
    ScopedExit<void> exitGuardOutter(foo);
    std::cout << "About to exit from the scope\n";
    return 0;
}
```

2) Should be created like `ScopedExit<void>`.